# Making a post request with elements created using an *ngFor loop in Angular with an Ionic grid

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've populated an `Ionic grid` with elements I've created using a get request from our database:

```
<ion-row [ngClass]="(i % 2 == 0) ? 'odd' : 'even'" style="border-radius: 20px; border-style: solid; border-color: grey; margin-top: 10px;" *ngFor="let bull of bulls; let i = index;">
```

Basically now that I've created the table, if some of the fields have been modified on the webpage I need to collect the modified objects and make a post request to the database to update the changed objects. How can I get access to these objects?

For example, if the html textbox containing the name of the bull has been changed, how can I get access to the table row at index i, where i is the index of the row with the changed value?

Comment: Can you share the code for how you get your field modified?

Comment: Popped an adderall and the rest fell into place. thanks tho you the man

Answer (score 0):

Added [(ngModel)]="bulls[i].DOB" ngDefaultControl to my html and it worked
(bulls is the public array where I keep load the get request into)

So now if I modify the values in this field and console.log(bulls[0].DOB) it will print the modified value